# Concatenating with DropDownList items ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have a databound dropdownlist on my asp.net page.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCases" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I am populating ddlCases as

```
ddlCases.DataSourse = SelectItems();
ddlCases.DataValueField = "itemid";
ddlCases.DataTextField = "itemname";
ddlCases.SelectedIndex = 0;
ddlCases.DataBind();
```

SelectItems() return a datatable.
What I want to do is to concatenate each item with a sequence number(1,2,3..) in which sequence they appear in the dropdownlist something like
 1. itemname1
 2. itemname2
 3. itemname3

What are my options for achieving this??
Regards,
ZB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with linq, something like this should work

```
ddlCases.DataSourse = SelectItems().Select((item, index) 
                                             => new{
                                                     index = index, 
                                                     itemid = item.itemid, 
                                                     itemname = index.ToString() + "." + item.itemname
                                                    });
ddlCases.DataValueField = "itemid";
ddlCases.DataTextField = "itemname";
ddlCases.SelectedIndex = 0;
ddlCases.DataBind();
```

**EDIT**

Select method creates another `IEnumerable`(collection) that contains new [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx),where index property is index in the first array, itemid is itemid and itemname index + itenmane

So shortly with LINQ statments we create another temporary class, that contains properties we want

Hope this make sense

**EDIT**

If SelectItems method returns untyped data table, as @VinayC suggested in the comment you should write

```
ddlCases.DataSourse = SelectItems()
.AsEnumerable().Select((r, i) => new { itemid = r["itemid"], itemname = i.ToString() + r["itemname"] })
```

Comment: Nice, that was quick. Can you elaborate a little as I am sorry but I am not linq expert, what are item and index. Should they match with the database columns I am retrieving.

Comment: I have added some more details, please take a look, does this works?

Comment: May be I am not properly understanding it but it says 'Cannot convert lambda expression to type string..'

Comment: In first line.. Actually my first line goes like ddlCases.DataSource = ItemsBAL.SelectItems(CatID).Select(....);

Comment: hmm, try to add .ToArray in the end

Comment: @ArsenMkrt, this may not work for a (untyped) data-table. The code needs to be changed something like `SelectItems().AsEnumerable().Select(r, i) => new { itemid = r["itemid"], itemname = i.ToString() + r["itemname"] })`

Comment: ahh, sure if SelectedItems return untyped data table, thanks for help

Comment: Tnx for ur time and help guys.. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can handle the databound event and edit items in the list , try this code :

```
   protected void ddlCases_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ddlCases.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            ddlCases.Items[i].Text = i + 1 + ". " + ddlCases.Items[i].Text;
        }
    }
```